# Disabling and enabling jquery UI droppable not working

Tags: jquery-ui, droppable

I am trying to make a div that when it holds a droppable element, you won;t be able to drop another one on top of it, but when the draggable is removed - you can.
I use

```
$("#trash").droppable({
    out: function() {
        $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
    },
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
    }
});
```

But it `#trash` remains disabled after I move the droppable out, I don't understand why.
http://jsfiddle.net/vMQVy/38/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change to `$("#items").droppable()`:

```
$("#items").droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#trash").droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
        }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vMQVy/40/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!